# Gruntfile not found

Tags: sublimetext2, gruntjs

I am trying to use Sublime Text 2 with Grunt, but I can't get it working.

The watch task is working if I do it on the Windows console (so it is installed correctly), but not in ST, there it says "Gruntfile.js or Gruntfile.coffee not found" (using the Grunt plugin).

I have no idea why, because there is a folder called "build" containing the Gruntfile.js and the other stuff in the project directory.

I tried removing ST and the plugin and installed it again, but still the same problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Gruntfile should be at the root of the project.

http://gruntjs.com/getting-started#the-gruntfile

You can see the exact code that's throwing the error here: https://github.com/tvooo/sublime-grunt/blob/master/main.py#L41